# Cannot get Ruby gem Bundler to respect the '--without' option

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Somehow i cannot use `bundle install --without ...` as explained in [Bundler's documentation](http://bundler.io/groups.html).  Here is how i can reproduce this: create a new directory with just a Gemfile:

```ruby
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'not-a-gem', :group => :test
```

and run

```bash
bundle install --without test
```

I get the error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'not-a-gem (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this
machine.
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler always resolves the dependencies for all your gems, even if you're excluding a group.  Otherwise, it might overlook a conflict that will arise later when you don't exclude that group.

If all the gems and versions are valid and the dependencies are resolved properly, *then* Bundler will respect your wishes and not install gems in the group.

Comment: Does this mean that if a gem is a local gem that will only be available in production environment (or is not ready yet), the only workaround for development is to have a different Gemfile in development?